# Can't install Java

Tags: java

I've tried installing Java several times and although the installation is apparently successful when I run

```
$ java -version
```

I get

```
-bash: java: command not found
```

When I run

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

I get No alternatives for java.
I tried

```
$ jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

and got

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/ is not a valid path to java installation
```

Comment: How did you install Java ?

Comment: What java version did you attempt to install and what command did you use?

Comment: I attempted to install java 7, installed it from the oracle website

Comment: Is this Linux or MacOS? I would not use jenv until java works. Try to use the fill path to the java binary first. If this works you can add it to PATH. Oracle Java does not register alternatives (but you could do it manually).

Comment: it is MacOS. am unsure how to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

You're simply missing the `environment` variable...

edit `$HOME/.bash_profile`

Add

```
JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Also, modify the `PATH` to add the `bin` of `Java`

```
 PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME\bin
```

Make sure to recall `.bash_profile` if you do not reload `bash`

```
. $HOME/.bash_profile
```

now `java -version` should work.

Comment: No, tried that, still does not work

Comment: @user3089079 what is in the folder /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/ ?

Comment: there isn't a java folder under library

Comment: @user3089079 I just edited the path, pretty sure it will works now. Actually on `Mac` there is /Library folder and /System/Library... The second one contrains `Java` while we were using the first one.